# External Trigger for Jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Do we have an option  in jenkins to trigger a build remotely(externally) based on a secret token?
So that each dev team can be given the secret token in case they need to trigger  an emergency build

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jenkins remote access api for that

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Build trigger in Jenkins to remotely trigger it from scripts or REST client application. Set an authentication token which will be asked for once you select the Remotely Trigger option under Build Trigger in you Jenkins dashboard.

You can refer to this client application below:

```
public class BuildJob {
      private static String ENDPOINT ="http://IP OR LOCALHOST:8080/job/JOBNAME/build";
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
      { 
          String url = ENDPOINT;
          String charset = "UTF-8";
          String param1 = "mykey";

          String query = String.format("token=YOUR TOKEN", 
               URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset));
          java.net.URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
          if ( connection instanceof HttpURLConnection)
          {
             HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
             System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseCode());
             System.out.println(httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
          }
          else
          {
             System.err.println ("error!");
          }
      }
```

And you are all set to test now.

Answer (score 0):

Following curl command worked for me

curl -X POST -L --user <JenkinsUserName>:<Jenkins API token> https://<JenkinsJobURL>/build